# Trying to use proxy using selenium but not able to access any Https site

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Trying to open a site using proxy with selenium but the site is https site but I am not able to open https site

Below is the code which I wrote:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "159.203.11.15:80" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Shashank/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

Note: When I ran this code, the browser was showing "This site can't  be reached" message

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to reach the site it could be due to sslProxy not being set, so you're attempting to reach out only with the http configuration. Perhaps this will help :) input your proxy:port into both httpProxy & sslProxy. Alternatively, you could try firefox or a different proxy altogether.

I've had a quick look at the proxy you might be using, and it could be HTTP only. Which means you'll have to find a different proxy that supports HTTPS

```
capabilities = dict( DesiredCapabilities.CHROME )

if not "chromeOptions" in capabilities:
    capabilities['chromeOptions'] = {
        'args' : [],
        'binary' : "",
        'extensions' : [],
        'prefs' : {}
    }

capabilities['proxy'] = {
    'httpProxy' : "%s:%i" %(proxy_address, proxy_port),
    'ftpProxy' : "%s:%i" %(proxy_address, proxy_port),
    'sslProxy' : "%s:%i" %(proxy_address, proxy_port),
    'noProxy' : None,
    'proxyType' : "MANUAL",
    'class' : "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    'autodetect' : False
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path="path_to_chrome", desired_capabilities=capabilities, skip_capabilities_update=True )
```

Comment: The Site Can't be reached is still coming

Comment: What happens if you try to access the site via a different proxy?

Comment: @ShashankSahu Update my original post with more information on the proxy you might be using `159.203.11.15`. If the information was helpful, when you have a second, chuck it a mark ^^